# what alternative methods for sudo echo without bash -c

Tags: linux, bash, shell, escaping, sudo

I must run the `echo` in the script `my.sh` with `sudo` because permission.
I do not want to execute the script with `sudo my.sh`.
I do not want to use `bash -c "..."` because escaping.

Are there no other solutions?

my.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
>/file.tmp \
echo '
a="S T"
z=\a\b\c\
'
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  If you want the script to run the `echo` command via `sudo`, then what's wrong with putting `sudo` in front of `echo` in the script?  What does `bash -c` even have to do with it?

Comment: I assume you want to use `sudo` because you need write permission in the directory to create the output file. If that is the case, your solution will not work.  You do not need `echo` to run with elevated privileges; you need the shell doing the redirect to have permission.  The typical solution is to `echo ... | sudo tee...`

Comment: @JohnBollinger if you put ```sudo``` in front of ```echo``` you get a permission error because /file.tmp is in the root dir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are encountering here is that the output redirection `>/file.tmp` has to happen with elevated privileges. This means that you either have to launch the script as it is with `sudo my.sh`, or perform the redirection in a way that gives it elevated privileges. It is not enough to run `sudo echo` because only `echo` would have elevated privileges, but the output redirection would run as your non-root user because it is a shell builtin feature, not an external command.

There is a standard tool called `tee` that can help with this. This method is commonly used when running `curl` to fetch data that needs to be fed to root, such as [installing debian apt repository configurations and signing keys](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install-sdk#deb).

```
$ whoami
dho
$ whoami | sudo tee whoami.txt >/dev/null
$ ls -la whoami.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4 2022-06-03T09:08:22 whoami.txt
```

So you can see that I launched `whoami` with my own user, but the file ended up being written with root permissions because `tee`, which replaces the output redirection from your original example, was launched as `sudo tee`.